# Node.js: Difference between http finish event, response close event, and response end event

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, events

I'm new to NodeJS and after looking in the documentation and experimenting with the `http.on('finish')`, `res.on('close')`, and `res.on('end')`, I do not understand how each are different.

```js
http.get(url, res => {

        res.setEncoding('utf8'); // returns string object to data event
        res.on('data', string => {
            const responseObj = responseDataList.find(responseObj => {
                return responseObj.url === url;
            });
            responseObj.data += string;
        });
        res.on('close', () => {
            console.log('[Interruption] connection closed before response was ended.');  // Never fires
        })

        res.on('error', console.error);

        // TODO: find out difference between response.end and response.close and http.finish events
        res.on('end', (data, encoding) => {
            // Seems to fire at the same time that http.on('finish') fires
            current++;
    
            if (counter === current) {
                responseDataList.forEach(responseObj => {
                    console.log(responseObj.data);
                })
            }
        });
    })
    .on('error', console.error)
    .on('finish', () => {
        // Seems to fire at the same time that res.on('end') fires
        console.log('response sent')
    }); // emitted when the response is sent to the OS (not when it is received by the client)
```

When do each one fire and how are they different?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As soon as `http.get` calls your callback with the `res` object it returns an [`http.ClientRequest`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest). The `http.ClientRequest` inherits from [`Stream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream).

So, according to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish):

> The `finish` event is emitted after the `stream.end()` method has been called, and all data has been flushed to the underlying system.

In the case of `http.get`, `stream.end()` is called immediately after making the request (See [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback)). N.B. calling `stream.end()` is different from listening to the `res.on('end')` event.

So for `http.get`, the `finish` event will fire immediately after making the request and then the `res` object events will start firing.

Your `res` object is an [`HTTP.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) which implements the [`Readable Stream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) interface

According the the `Readable Stream` docs:

> The 'end' event is emitted when there is no more data to be consumed from the stream.

So `end` fires first then `close`

Also for `Readable Streams`

> The 'close' event is emitted when the stream and any of its underlying resources (a file descriptor, for example) have been closed. The event indicates that no more events will be emitted, and no further computation will occur.

So the events fire in this order: `finish`, `end`, `close`